# Is there a way to validate a schema against a groovy map?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My use case is Jenkins specific but this is a general Groovy question

I have a map I want to apply a schema to. If this map is missing fields or some fields are of the wrong type (string/int/list/map/etc) I want to throw a clear error message that explains where the map doesn't match the schema.

I pass a map in my Jenkinsfile to a function in my shared library like this, so mypipeline would need to include the schema validation piece:

```
#Jenkinsfile
@Library('my-shared-lib') _

mypipeline ([

    'validate-this-map': [

        // manditory-param-one must exist and be a list
        'manditory-param-one': ["aaa","bbb","ccc"] 

        // manditory-param-two must exist and be a map
        'manditory-param-two': [
            "manditory-one": "111", // must include this field and be a string
            "manditory-two": "222", // must include this field and be a string
            "optional": "33",
        ]

        // manditory-param-three must exist and be a list of maps that have specific fields
        'manditory-param-three': [
            "manditory-one": [
                // all maps in this list must have these two fields
                "aaa": true // validate bool
                "bbb": "sdfsfdsd" //validate string
            ]
        ]

        'optional-param': "sdfsdfs" // ignore this. dont fail if this is here
    ]

])
```

What I have done in the past is things like translate the language specific construct (in this case a groovy Map) to json and apply a jsonschema which supports advanced features like recursion, etc. That can be wonky though and I want to know if this is possible in an idiomatic groovy way.

I don't want to make `validate-this-map` a class because that would complicate the Jenkinsfile config I *think*. Is there a way I can have groovy translate a map into a class and have groovy validate the class properties or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Groovy's named parameter in constructor facility and create object hierarchies automagically.

Then you can sprinkle it with simple validation, I used `Groovy Truth` down bellow for simplicity.

The code (after some clean-up of JSON keys) could look like:

```
import groovy.transform.*

// your classes

@ToString
class A {
  List<String> manditoryParamOne
  ManditoryParamTwo manditoryParamTwo
  ManditoryParamThree manditoryParamThree

  String optionalParam

  boolean asBoolean() {
    manditoryParamOne && manditoryParamTwo && manditoryParamThree
  }
}

@ToString
class ManditoryParamTwo {
  String manditoryOne, manditoryTwo, optional

  boolean asBoolean() {
    manditoryOne && manditoryTwo
  }
}
@ToString
class ManditoryParamThree {
  ManditoryOne manditoryOne

  boolean asBoolean() {
    manditoryOne
  }
}

@ToString
class ManditoryOne{
  Boolean aaa
  String bbb

  boolean asBoolean() {
    null != aaa && bbb
  }
}

// some test code, pay attention to map keys

def mapValid = [
        // manditory-param-one must exist and be a list
        'manditoryParamOne': ["aaa","bbb","ccc"],

        // manditory-param-two must exist and be a map
        'manditoryParamTwo': [
            "manditoryOne": "111", // must include this field and be a string
            "manditoryTwo": "222", // must include this field and be a string
            "optional": "33",
        ],

        // manditory-param-three must exist and be a list of maps that have specific fields
        'manditoryParamThree': [
            "manditoryOne": [
                // all maps in this list must have these two fields
                "aaa": true, // validate bool
                "bbb": "sdfsfdsd" //validate string
            ]
        ],

        'optionalParam': "sdfsdfs" // ignore this. dont fail if this is here
]
A a = new A( mapValid )
assert a.toString() == 'A([aaa, bbb, ccc], ManditoryParamTwo(111, 222, 33), ManditoryParamThree(ManditoryOne(true, sdfsfdsd)), sdfsdfs)'
assert true == !!a
assert true == !!a.manditoryParamOne
assert true == !!a.manditoryParamTwo

def mapInvalid = [
        'manditoryParamTwo': [
            "manditoryOne": "111", // must include this field and be a string
            "manditoryTwo": "222", // must include this field and be a string
            "optional": "33",
        ],

        // manditory-param-three must exist and be a list of maps that have specific fields
        'manditoryParamThree': [
            "manditoryOne": [
                "bbb": "sdfsfdsd" //validate string
            ]
        ]
]
A aa = new A( mapInvalid )
assert false == !!aa
assert true == !!aa.manditoryParamTwo
assert false == !!aa.manditoryParamThree
```

Comment: what is `@ToString` doing here?

Comment: to demonstrate the content of each object.